How to Add Second Page MetroLog.Maui
I'm trying to add logging to the second page of a Maui app using MetroLog.Maui.
My MainPage is logging to console and file with no problems, but I am struggling with how to add the logging to the NewPage1 (second page).
Here is the MetroLog code from my MauiProgram.
            builder.Logging
#if DEBUG
    .AddTraceLogger(
        options =>
        {
            options.MinLevel = LogLevel.Trace;
            options.MaxLevel = LogLevel.Critical;
        }) // Will write to the Debug Output

    .AddStreamingFileLogger(
                options =>
                {
                    options.RetainDays = 2;
                    options.FolderPath = Path.Combine(
                        FileSystem.CacheDirectory,
                        "MetroLogs");
                })

#endif
    .AddInMemoryLogger(
        options =>
        {
            options.MaxLines = 1024;
            options.MinLevel = LogLevel.Debug;
            options.MaxLevel = LogLevel.Critical;
        })
#if RELEASE
            .AddStreamingFileLogger(
                options =>
                {
                    options.RetainDays = 2;
                    options.FolderPath = Path.Combine(
                        FileSystem.CacheDirectory,
                        "MetroLogs");
                })
#endif
    .AddConsoleLogger(
        options =>
        {
            options.MinLevel = LogLevel.Information;
            options.MaxLevel = LogLevel.Critical;
        }); // Will write to the Console Output (logcat for android)

            {
                builder.Services.AddTransient<MainPage>();

#if DEBUG
                builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

                return builder.Build();
            }
        }
    }

And here is how I setup my MainPage.
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
 {
     private int count = 0;
     private ILogger<MainPage> _logger;

     public MainPage(ILogger<MainPage> logger)
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         _logger = logger;
     }

     private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         count++;

         if (count == 1)
             CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} time";
         else
             CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} times";

         SemanticScreenReader.Announce(CounterBtn.Text);

         _logger.LogInformation("Counter clicked {Count} times", count);
     }

     private void OnLogClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         //Navigate to the log page
         Navigation.PushAsync(new NewPage1());
         _logger.LogInformation("Navigated to the log page");
     }
 }

What should my signature be for the second page? or am I missing something else.
Here is my modified code for NewPage1 that works.
using MetroLog;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System.Reflection;
using System;

namespace SerilogMaui1;

public partial class NewPage1 : ContentPage
{
   
    public ILogger<MainPage> Logger { get; }


    public NewPage1(ILogger<MainPage> logger)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
           Logger = logger;
    }

    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Logger.LogInformation("clicked button in NewPage1");
        await DisplayAlert("Alert", "You have been alerted", "OK");
    }
}


Here is my new code for NewPage1 with changes and it is working.

Here is the code for NewPage1 that works.
using MetroLog;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System.Reflection;
using System;

namespace SerilogMaui1;

public partial class NewPage1 : ContentPage
{
   
    public ILogger<MainPage> Logger { get; }


    public NewPage1(ILogger<MainPage> logger)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
           Logger = logger;
    }

    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Logger.LogInformation("clicked button in NewPage1");
        await DisplayAlert("Alert", "You have been alerted", "OK");
    }
}

